# How to return few values using map

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have function that loops array and I have four if's - if it match I push value to output array:

```
const generate = (resources, resourceId) => {
    let output = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < resources.length; i++) {
        if (resources[i].id === resourceId) {
            if (CREATE & resources[i].privileges) {
                output.push(CREATE);
            }

            if (READ & resources[i].privileges) {
                output.push(READ);
            }

            if (UPDATE & resources[i].privileges) {
                output.push(UPDATE);
            }

            if (DELETE & resources[i].privileges) {
                output.push(DELETE);
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
};
```

I want to change this function to use `map` - is it possible? I try to do something like this:

```
const generateUsingMap = (resources, resourceId) => {
    return resources.map((resource) => {
        if (resource.id === resourceId) {
            if (CREATE & resource.privileges) {
                return CREATE;
            }
    
            if (READ & resource.privileges) {
                return READ;
            }
    
            if (UPDATE & resource.privileges) {
                return UPDATE;
            }
    
            if (UPDATE & resource.privileges) {
                return UPDATE;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

But in this case I will have only one value, because it returns from first if.
Maybe I need to use another function? I don't want to use for or forEach because in that cases I need to create unnecessary variable.

*Update*

My function is working in loop, function receive 2 arguments `resources` and `resourceId`.
For example variable `resources` contains:

```
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Test name 1",
    "privileges": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Test name 2",
    "privileges": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Test name 3",
    "privileges": 8
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Test name 4",
    "privileges": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Test name 5",
    "privileges": 15
  }
]
```

Variable `resourceId` contains number (id) and receive severally values, for example on first iteration 1, for second 2 and so on.

For resources from example expected output will be:

```
[1]
[2]
[8]
[]
[1,2,4,8]
```

Comment: what are `CREATE`, `READ` and `UPDATE` ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee this is const with some values.

Comment: Why would you used Bitwise `&` but rather logical `&&`?

Comment: @BasheerKharoti because I have binary values in that constants

Comment: Your question needs more details. You're making it much complicated now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce if both resource object id and privileges do not exist do not check further just return what you already accrued.

Only if both are present then check the CRUD operations.

```
const result = resources.reduce((output) => {
  if (resources[i].id !== resourceId && !resources[i].privileges) {
    return output;
  }
  if (CREATE) {
    output.push(CREATE);
  }
  if (READ) {
    output.push(READ);
  }

  if (UPDATE) {
    output.push(UPDATE);
  }

  if (DELETE) {
    output.push(DELETE);
  }
  return output;
}, [])
```

Comment: Almost work, but it return wrong array with to much elements.

Comment: @IvanPruchai well it should just collect the items that have CRUD and id and privileges props

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty array `resultArr`. Iterate through `resources` via `forEach` and append options to it. Return the array at the end of the function

```
const generateUsingMap = (resources, resourceId) => {
const resultArr = [];
resources.forEach((resource) => {
    if (resource.id === resourceId && resource.privileges) {
         if (CREATE) {
            resultArr.push(CREATE);
        }

        else if (READ) {
            resultArr.push(READ);
        }

        else if (UPDATE) {
            resultArr.push(UPDATE);
        }

        else if (DELETE) {
            resultArr.push(DELETE);
        }
    }
  });
 return resultArr;
};
```

Comment: Doesn't work as expected - return object that pass if, but I need array of values from consts (CREATE, READ etc).

Comment: With `else if` it will return only one value. And also for or forEach is badly for me, because using them I need to create unnecessary variable.

Comment: @IvanPruchai so you can just change `else if` to only `ifs` depending on your need. I believe there's no other option then creating a temp array which will store the result you need or otherwise add example output to your code so I can change it accordingly

Comment: @IvanPruchai I believe `Euen Sugen` answer's should work for you or if that's still not working you need to add a plunker and expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
const generateUsingMap = (resources, resourceId) => {
    return resources.filter(resource => resource.id === resourceId)
        .map((resource) => {
            if (CREATE & resource.privileges) {
                return CREATE;
            }

            if (READ & resource.privileges) {
                return READ;
            }

            if (UPDATE & resource.privileges) {
                return UPDATE;
            }

            if (UPDATE & resource.privileges) {
                return UPDATE;
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: Code looks better because you reduce one if using filter, but the problem remains - `map` function is return only one value from first passed if.

Comment: if the source and target are not one-one relationship, map is not a good choice.